# React-Native : How to change state of root component with Navigator according to number of routes

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a TabBarMenu (which is a basic View component) that I'd like to gide when there are more than 2 routes in the stack..

I've tried to do it this way but it crashes saying I try to update in the render method

> 2016-05-10 12:38:27.901 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript]
>   Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure
>   function of props and state.

Here is the code I tried :

```
hideMenu = () => {
  this.setState({displayMenu: false});
};

showMenu = () => {
  this.setState({displayMenu: true});
};

renderScene = (tab, navigator) => {
  if (navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) {
    this.hideMenu();
  } else {
    if (!this.state.displayMenu) {
      this.showMenu();
    }
  }
  return React.createElement(tab.component, _.extend({navigator: navigator}, tab.passProps));
};

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.tabbarContainer}>
      <Navigator
        ref='tabs'
        key='navigator'
        style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', flex: 1}}
        initialRoute={_.extend(this.props.tabs[this.props.initialSelected || 0])}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        configureScene={() => {
          return {
            ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid,
            defaultTransitionVelocity: 1000,
            gestures: {}
          };
        }} />
      {this.state.displayMenu ? [
        <Menu
          key='menu'
          style={styles.menu}
          active={this.state.active}
          tabs={this.props.tabs}
          tabsBlocked={this.props.tabsBlocked} 
          resetToTab={(index) => this.resetToTab(index)} />
      ] : null}
    </View>
  );
};
```

The issue comes from the `renderScene` function, but I can't find another way to achieve this. Any guesses how I could do it ?